# Using recurrence tree, solve the recurrence T(n) = T(n − 1) + O(n)

Tags: data-structures, tree, recurrence

Please Explain it.Using recurrence tree, solve the recurrence T(n) = T(n − 1) + O(n)

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? This tutorial contains some example, you can refer it https://www.javatpoint.com/daa-recursion-tree-method

Answer (score 1):

You build the recurrence tree by repeatedly expanding the term on the right side. This tree is actually just a chain, as each node in that tree only has one child:

```
                         O(n)
                          |
                         O(n-1)
                          |
                         O(n-2)
                          |
                          ...
```

The height of this tree is *n*, and the sum of the terms is

Σ<sub><sub>*i=1..n*</sub></sub>*O(i)*

...which is:

*O*( Σ<sub><sub>*i=1..n*</sub></sub>*i* )

...which is (cf. [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)):

*O*( *n(n+1)/2* )

...which is:

*O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>).